# Connection Closed Next-Auth

Tags: typescript, next.js, discord, next-auth

So im trying to implement next-auth discord with my application, but every time i click on log in with discord, it returns a error saying that connection closed, no idea why, the logs arent explicit:
[image]

ive tried disabling any extension that may cause any trouble, i disabled Hot Module Replacement bc before i was getting a websocket error, i checked for any proccesses interfering, checked for antivirus, updating dependencies but nothing works

Comment: What does Wireshark say?

Comment: currently i dont use wireshark

Comment: Well now you'll have to - otherwise you won't be able to diagnose the issue.

Comment: i recorded with wireshark but i dont understand anything, how do i read this things and how do i know that they have something to do with next-auth

Comment: Look for TCP `RST` or `FIN` or similar.

Comment: there is no explicit FIN but there is a RST:
61 9.872805 Source Destination TCP 54 57445 → 443 [RST, ACK] Seq=26 Ack=25 Win=0 Len=0